# Dynamically create Canvas and add onmousedown functionality

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I need to dynamically create multiple canvas elements at run time. I've managed to create the canvas' fine, but setting the 'onmousedown' attribute to a method has proven difficult. This may be bacuse I need to pass the canvas element through the function, although I am not sure. Can anyone help?

Thank you!

Below you can see, in order: the original static canvas, the loop to dynamically create canvas' and the function I need to set as 'onmousedown'.

```
<canvas id="Canvas1" onmousedown="MouseDown(this, event)" onmousemove="MouseMove(event)" onmouseup="MouseUp(event)" width="0" height="600" style="overflow: hidden; position: absolute; top: 0px;">

for(var i = 1; i < total; i++)
{
    var div = document.getElementById("Control");
    var canv = document.createElement('canvas');
    canv.id = "Canvas" + i.toString();         
    canv.width= 0+'px';
    canv.height= 600+'px';
    canv.style.overflow = 'hidden';
    canv.style.position = 'absolute'; 
    canv.style.top = 0+'px';

    div.appendChild(canv);
}

function MouseDown(can, e)
{

    MovingCanvas = can;
    alert("got here");
    clicked = true;
    MouseX = e.clientX;
    MouseY = e.clientY;

    StartX = MovingCanvas.style.left;
    StartY = MovingCanvas.style.top;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the callback handler inside the loop:

```
for(var i = 1; i < total; i++) {

    --- 8X ---

    /// add a callback handler here by referencing the function
    canv.onmousedown = MouseDown;

    div.appendChild(canv);
}
```

Note that this will only give one argument, the event. But there is no need as the callback will bind the current canvas that invoke the callback as `this`; so you can rather modify your callback function:

```
/// callback only gives one argument to the function, the event
function MouseDown(e) {

    /// this will be current canvas that called this function
    MovingCanvas = this;

    --- 8X ---
}
```

and then of course this needs to be modified as well:

```
<canvas id="Canvas1" onmousedown="MouseDown(event)" ...
                                            ^^^^^
```